# Python-Unable to convert a list to string

Tags: python, string, list, python-3.x, type-conversion

**What I was trying to do:**

> Take a string and append a backwards copy of that string, making a
>   palindrome

**What I came up with:**

```
# take an input string
a = input('Please enter a string: ')
a = list(a)

# read the string backwards
b = list(reversed(a))

# append the backward-ordered string to the original string, and print this new string
c = a + b
c = str(c)

print(c)
```

**Question:** When given a run, this script takes a string, for example "test", and returns `['t', 'e', 's', 't', 't', 's', 'e', 't']`; I'm confused about this result since I explicitly converted `c`, as a result of concatenation of `a` and `b`, to a string. (`c = str(c)`) I know I must have missed some basic stuff here, but I wasn't able to figure out what. Could someone throw some light on this? Thank you!

**And** would anyone care to elaborate on why my `c = str(c)` didn't work? Thanks!

Comment: Just turn the list c back into a string like this: c = "".join(a+b) instead of c=str(c).

Comment: Im pretty sure it's a string but the commas and brackets are with the string

Comment: You don't actually need `a = list(a)` here. A string is already a sequence of characters, and you can already call `reversed` on it.

Comment: @abarnert thanks for pointing that out! I must have missed that. But on a related note, if `a` is set to be a string, would one be able to concatenate it with `b`? (i'm thinking about `b=list(reversed(a))`here), or is there another way (like `b=reversed(a)`? can you do that?)

Comment: If you want to use `b=reversed(a)` instead of `b=a[::-1]`, then you will have to `join` up `b`, just as in nrpeterson's answer. Compactly: `a + ''.join(reversed(a))`. You may find that more readable than `a + a[::-1]`, even though it requires some extra converting—if so, always go for the more readable version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with saying `c = str(c)` is that applying `str` to a list simply gives a string representation *of that list* - so, for instance, `str([1,2,3])` yields the string `'[1, 2, 3]'`.

The easiest way to make a list of strings in to a string is to use the `str.join()` method.  Given a string `s` and a list `a` of strings, running `s.join(a)` returns a string formed by joining the elements of `a`, using `s` as the glue.

For instance:

```
a = ['h','e','l','l','o']
print( ''.join(a) ) # Prints: hello
```

Or:

```
a = ['Hello', 'and', 'welcome']
print( ' '.join(a) ) # Prints: Hello and welcome
```

Finally:

```
a = ['555','414','2799']
print( '-'.join(a) ) # Prints: 555-414-2799
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! and could you tell me  why my `c = str(c)` didn't work? Thanks!

Comment: str(c) actually gives a string representation of the list, rather than forming a string out of the elements of the list.  (So, it includes the brackets and commas!)

Comment: but at the beginning of my code, `a =list(a)` worked. Is there a difference between `a=list(a)` and `c=str(c)` ? (other than the fact that the former converts a to a list and the latter intends to convert c to string?)

Comment: Absolutely.  `str` is a type conversion function - the idea is to come up with a string that represents the passed argument as faithfully as possible. So, if you pass it a list, it gives you what it thinks is a good string representation of a list - namely, with brackets to separate it from its surroundings, and commas to separate elements.  The `list` function, on the other hand, is set up to take any object that acts like an iterator, and return a list of its contents.

Comment: great answer! thanks. Can i just add one real quick: so whenever I use str(), Python is actually trying to come up with a string representation of that object as close as it can? and in this specific case Python's guess was a bit off? is this how I should understand it? thanks

Comment: Well, Python isn't actually making a decision of course; when you call `str(object)`, python translates it in to a call to the method `object.__str__()`; whoever wrote the class that is the type of `object` determined what they thought the best string representation was.  Since a list of numbers, a list of strings, and a list of various types of objects all just have the same type `list`, the designers of python didn't want to make too many assumptions.

Comment: I can understand it better now after your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
in_str = input('Please enter a string: ')
a = list(in_str)
b=a+a[::-1]
print (''.join(b))
```

Prints:

```
Please enter a string: test
testtset
```

And there is actually no reason to convert to a list first for this case since you can index, reverse and concatenate the string directly in Python:

```
>>> s='test'
>>> s+s[::-1]
'testtset'
```

Which shows a common idiom in Python to test if a string is a palindrome:

```
>>> pal='tattarrattat'
>>> pal==pal[::-1]
True
```

Comment: Why convert the string to a list? Strings are already sliceable sequences of characters, so the same thing would work without the conversion—and you wouldn't need to `join` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth understanding how to use `join`—and nrpeterson's answer does a great job explaining that.

But it's *also* worth knowing how not to create problems for yourself to solve.

Ask yourself why you've called `a = list(a)`. You're trying to convert a string to a sequence of characters, right? But a string is *already* a sequence of characters. You can call `reversed` on it, you can loop over it, you can slice it, etc. So, this is unnecessary.

And, if you've left `a` as a string, the slice `a[::-1]` is *also* a string.

That means your whole program can reduce to this:

```
a = input('Please enter a string: ')

# read the string backwards
b = a[::-1]

# append the backward-ordered string to the original string, and print this new string
c = a + b

print(c)
```

Or, more simply:

```
a = input('Please enter a string: ')

print(a + a[::-1])
```

Comment: great answer! then please ignore my reply to your comment above. Thank you for this elegant solution! I'm sure that i have a lot to learn!

Answer (score 0):

```
def make_palindrome(string):
    return string + string[::-1]

make_palindrome(input('Please enter a String: '))
```